# Block Content dentro de un include

Tags: django, django-templates

En mi template base tengo varios includes con las difrentes partes de la  plantilla, en un include tengo el header en otro el menu, en otro el footer, y en el del main tengo dentro un {block content}, el problema es que cuando heredo ese base y quiero meterle el contenido con {% block content %} no se llega a visualizar nunca. Mi pregunta es si es posible usar los block content dentro de los archivos a los que llamas desde un include.

```
base.html 
......
{% include "metronic/project/layout/_scrolltop.html" %}

{% include "metronic/project/partials/modals/create-app/_main.html" %}  

{% include "metronic/project/partials/modals/_invite-friends.html" %}
......


_main.html
...........
{% block main %}
{% endblock %}
........


templateUser.html
{% extends 'base.html' %}
..........
{% block main %}
.....
{% endblock %}
............
```

Cuando se renderiza el templateuser.html que usa la vista se ve todo lo del base y lo de los 3 includes pero lo que tengo en el block main que debería ir dentro de la parte del include del _main.html no se ve , si saco el block del include del _main.html y lo pongo en el base , si que se ve, pero necesito que tenga un block ese _main.html.

Comment: Hola, por favor, incluye parte del código para poder brindarte una guía

Comment: He añadido como tengo distribuida la herencia de plantillas para que sea algo mas ilustrativo

Answer (score 0):

La herencia de bloques no es transversal. Estás tratando de heredar el bloque desde _main y debería ser desde base.html, que es el template padre